# How to create a single page using Drupal Commerce containing product, billing infor payment method?

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to create a donation form as product, but I want the billing information/Account Information form and Payment method options to be in a single page together instead of having them on a different process page.

Is this possible?

Is there a way to configure this in [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) or is there a programmatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkout flow uses panes, and there is nothing hindering you to put all of the panes in a single page and skip the review page if you wanted to. This can be setup in the checkout settings with a simple drag and drop interface. Should be fairly simple to setup the way you want to out of the box.

Comment: thanks, I have put billing information form and payment method in a single page.. but is it possible to put these two forms in one page with my donation form?